# XmlElement tags ignored for XML Serialization from WCF service

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I'm trying to customize how my object is being serialized from a WCF service, however the serializer is ignoring all my `[XmlAttribute]` and `[XmlElement(DataType="date")]` tags.

```
public Invoice Get(Int32 Id)
{
    return new Invoice();
}

public class Invoice
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(DataType="date")]
    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    //..etc
}
```

When I call the service, the response I get back is:

```
<Invoice>
    <Type>MyType</Type>
    <InvoiceDate>2015-03-02T22:41:22.5221045-05:00</InvoiceDate>
</Invoice>
```

What I'm looking for is:

```
<Invoice Type="MyType">
    <InvoiceDate>2015-03-02</InvoiceDate>
</Invoice>
```

Answer (score 2):

By default the class will be serialized using the **DataContract** serializer and so you should be annotating your properties with attributes such as ...

```
[DataContract(Name = "Invoice")]
public class Invoice
{
    [IgnoreDataMemberAttribute]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "InvoiceDate ", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set;}
}
```

None of the default attributes for the DataContract serializer will cause it to change the type of the value output, in order to truncate your DateTime to just a date value. To achieve this you would need to implement the **IXmlSerializable** interface so you can control the serialization and deserialization of the class at a detailed level.